# How to configure Dedicated IPs for specific SES domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Recently we've requested for 2 dedicated IPs for our SES domain, As most of the mails are going to spam folder. And we've 5-6 SES domains(account.abc.com, help.abc.com, mail.abc.com, etc) in the same aws account, But we would like to use these dedicated Ips only for specific domain(mail.abc.com). Is there any way to set/configure dedicated ips only for specific domain to avoid bad ip reputation?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?